# How to set state in React after successful Firebase set?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following function to save my app's state to a Firebase ref:

```
saveResultsToDatabase() {

    const {
      companyName, companyUrl, productName, goals, industries,
      ageRanges, gender, other, weightedScores, goalScores, industryScores, ageScores, recommendation,
      email, phone, optin
    } = this.state

    const databaseObject = {
      companyName, companyUrl, productName, goals, industries,
      ageRanges, gender, other, weightedScores, goalScores, industryScores, ageScores, recommendation,
      email, phone, optin
    }


    contactRef.push().set((databaseObject), function(error) {
      if (error) {

        console.log(error)
      } else {
        this.setState({savedToDatabase: true})
      }
    })
```

I want to update the "savedToDatabase" object in my state on successful Firebase execution. However, this does not work. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: i guess `function()` is change `this` scope, try change it to an arrow function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `function() {}` of the callback for for firebase action `this` is different to the `this` of the component. One option is to use an arrow function instead which binds to the context of this.

You can read more about this here: https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4

e.g.

```
contactRef.push().set((databaseObject),(error) => {
  // do something
  this.setState({})
}
```

This should work.

Another option which you might've seen previous is by using `var self = this` approach

```
var self = this;
contactRef.push().set((databaseObject), function(error) {
  // do something
  self.setState({})
}
```